# Dynamics CRM SDK - IN operator for linq with OrganizationServiceContext

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I'm using my OrganizationServiceContext implementation generated by the svcutil to retrieve entities from CRM:

```
context.new_productSet.First(p => p.new_name == "Product 1");
```

Is it possible to retrieve multiple entities with different attribute values at once - (smth like IN operator in SQL)?

Example: I would like to retrieve multiple products ("Product 1", "Product 2", ...) with a single call. The list of product names is dynamic, stored in an array called productNames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't. CRM LINQ provider only allows variables to appear on the left side of expressions, while the right side must contain constants.

i.e.

```
Product.Where(e => e.Name == desiredName)
```

Is not supported and won't work (it will complain about using a variable on the right side of the comparison).

If you cannot avoid this kind of query, you have to `.ToList()` data first (this can lead to a **huge** result set and will probably turn up to be unconceivably slow):

```
Product.ToList().Where(e => e.Name == desiredName)
```

This will work, because now the `.Where()` is being applied on a `List<>` instead.

Another approach (I don't have data about performance, though) would be to create many queries, basically fetching the records one at a time:

```
// ... this is going to be a nightmare ... don't do it ...
var entities = new List<Product>();
entities.Add(Product.Where(e => e.Name == "Product 1"));
entities.Add(Product.Where(e => e.Name == "Product 2"));
```

Or use a `QueryExpression` like this (my personal favourite, because I always go late-bound)

```
var desiredNames = new string[]{"Product 1", "Product 2"};
var filter = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And)
{
    Conditions = 
    {
        new ConditionExpression("name", ConditionOperator.In, desiredNames)
    }
};
var query = new QueryExpression(Product.EntityLogicalName)
{
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true),
    Criteria = filter
};
var records = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
```

Comment: What is the maximum limit for in clause ?

Comment: Rather than `.ToList()`, you can use `.AsEnumerable()`, and then use Linq-to-objects to further transform the data.

Answer (score 6):

If combining Linq and Lambda expression is ok, it can be done. First you need to create an extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Kipon.Dynamics.Extensions.IQueryable
{
    public static class Methods
    {
        public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIn<TSource, TValue>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TValue>> valueSelector, IEnumerable<TValue> values)
        {
            if (null == source) { throw new ArgumentNullException("source"); }
            if (null == valueSelector) { throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector"); }
            if (null == values) { throw new ArgumentNullException("values"); }

            var equalExpressions = new List<BinaryExpression>();

            foreach (var value in values)
            {
                var equalsExpression = Expression.Equal(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value));
                equalExpressions.Add(equalsExpression);
            }

            ParameterExpression p = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();
            var combined = equalExpressions.Aggregate<Expression>((accumulate, equal) => Expression.Or(accumulate, equal));
            var combinedLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, bool>>(combined, p);

            return source.Where(combinedLambda);
        }
    }
}
```

With this method in place, you can now use it against your context. First remember to import the namespace of the extension to make the method available on IQueryable:

```
using System.Linq;
using Kipon.Dynamics.Extensions.IQueryable;

public class MyClass
  {
     void myQueryMethod(CrmContext ctx, Guid[] contacts) 
     {
       var accounts = (from a in ctx.accountSet.WhereIn(ac => ac.primarycontactid.id,contacts)
                       where a.name != null
                       select a).toArray();
     }
}
```

There is no way you can hook into the Dynamics 365 Linq expression compiler, as far as I know, but the above code will execute in one request against the CRM, and take advantage
of the fact that you do not need to consider paging and more when working with Linq.

As you can see, there whereIn clause is added with a lambda style expression, where the rest of the query is using the Linq style.

Comment: Is there a way to combine the extension WhereIn() with joins? Tried to do that unsuccessfully :( Nevertheless, great answer!

Comment: try do the WhereIn on the joined query instead of joining an additonal entity on the WhereIn query. The order of execution is important to the CRM SDK query mapper.

(from a in first
 join b in second on ....
 select new { a, b}
 ).WhereIn()

Comment: If you use this logic with large numbers of items it will cause an error. The Dynamics Linq Query Provider appears to have a bug where it will cause an StackOverflowException on queries with deeply nested where clauses. This results in an HTTP 502 error. In our testing we see that we can get about 340 items in the where clause for a query before we run into this issue.

Comment: To John, your are right, but that is due to the fact that this approach is converting the in operations to an "OR'ed block of N eq 'a' or N eq 'b', and there is a limitation on the length of the fetch xml. The alternative is to actually use fetch xml, where IN is supported, it is just the LINQ provider og the Dataverse SDK that does not support it. That approach will also eventually fail with large numbers of elements in the "in list" due to limitation of max query length.  I often end up creating my linq expression with inner joins and conditions on the related table, so one query solves all.

Answer (score 2):

When using QueryExpression, we can add condtionexpression for where clause. ConditionExpression takes a ConditionOperator enumerator, and we can use ConditionOperator.In. Below is how you initiate a conidtionExpression with an “In” operator, the third argument can be an array or collection.

```c#
ConditionExpression ce = new ConditionExpression("EntityName",
        ConditionOperator.In, collectionObject);
```

Please see below for further explanation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.query.conditionexpression.conditionexpression.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do this with Linq, as far as I know it is not possible.

It can be done with Query Expressions:

```c#
String[] productNames = new[] { "test1", "test2" };
QueryExpression products = new QueryExpression(Product.EntityLogicalName);
products.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name", "new_att1", "new_att2"); // fields to get 
products.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.In,
    productNames.Cast<Object>().ToArray()); // filter by array
EntityCollection res = service.RetrieveMultiple(products);
IEnumerable<Product> opportunities = res.Entities
    .Select(product => product.ToEntity<Product>()); // you can use Linq again from here
```